# Unity minimizing app size

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

I am working on a unity project using vuforia and the vuforia video playback. The project involves adding a lot of mp4 files directly into the project directory because the vuforia video playback needs a local path to the video. The unity project is now up to 3.2 GB, and I just started development. Are there any ways to combat this issue of this app potentially getting way too large?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend storing your larger files in an [Asset Bundle](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AssetBundlesIntro.html). Asset Bundles allow you to store your content online, and download it when necessary (once opened after install, or after the user has paid for the content). You can access your assets locally using the Asset Bundle directory:

`Application.dataPath + "/AssetBundles/" + assetBundleName`

Comment: The app will potentially have 100,000 thousands of mp4 files, would the asset bundle download all of those files upon opening the app after install?

Comment: This sounds a little unfeasable, are you expecting your users to watch all 100,000 videos?? Generally in these cases you would stream your videos.

Comment: If you did need to store them all locally, yes, you theoretically could download them after opening the app on install, but depending on the size of your files, it might take too long to download on a slow connection or use up too much of your user's data allowance. You can have multiple Asset Bundles, so I'd consider sorting your videos into smaller groups and download them when necessary.

Comment: Thanks, i figured out a way to externally play the videos on a texture. So i stored all the videos on amazon s3.

Answer (score 0):

Compress the files as much as possible until you see some visible quality drop. You just need to find the best combination of video resolution and audio / video bit rates.